# Excel formula for Financial/Fiscal year July 1st to June 30th

Tags: excel

Question 1 : How can I set the Month of the Financial/Fiscal Year for this excel formula? 
If the date is July 1 or July 3, 2005 then the result should be **1**. If the date is August 5, 2005 then the result should be **2**. If the date is January 13, 2006 then the result should be **7**. Because our Financial/Fiscal year starts from July 1 and ends on June 30th. Example would be July 1, 2005 to June 30, 2006.

This is the formula that I have but it only applies for January 1, I need a formula that starts on the 1st of July.

```
=MONTH(A1-(1+ DATE(YEAR(A1),6,31)-DATE(YEAR(A1),1,1)))
```

Because our company Financial/Fiscal Year starts on July 1st. I need to get the month number of each day in a year and it's corresponding MONTH NUMBER, but the First day should be July 1st and not January 1.

---

Question 2 :  How can I set the Quarter of the Financial/Fiscal Year for this excel formula? The First day should be July 1st and not January 1. 
The result should be like this, if the date is July 1, 2005 then the output should be **Q1,2005**. If the date is January 11, 2006 then the output should be **Q3,2005** and not **Q3, 2006**. The excel formula below is what I have, but it is only good for January 1st and not July 1st.

```
="Q"&LOOKUP(MONTH(A4),{1,4,7,10},{1,2,3,4})&", "&TEXT(A4,"yyyy")
```

---

Question 3 : How can I set the Financial Half Year of Year?

If the date in Cell A1 is between July 1, 2005 to July 31, 2005 then the output on Cell B2 should be **Jul to Dec 2005**, same with the other dates such as January 1st to January 31, 2008 then output should be **Jan to Jun 2008**. Cell A1 is where I put the dates from July 1, 2005 up to December 31, 2025.

Many Thanks!!

Beau

Comment: It would be better to have asked these as separate questions. as a hint, you might want to look at the `MOD()` function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming date in A1 in all cases try this for Question 1

`=MONTH(EDATE(A1,6))`

and for Question 2

`="Q"&LOOKUP(MONTH(A1),{1,4,7,10},{3,4,1,2})&", "&YEAR(A1+184)-1`

....and for Question 3

`=IF(MONTH(A1)>6,"Jul to Dec ","Jan to Jun ")&YEAR(A1)`

Answer (score 0):

If A1 contains a date, then in another cell enter:

**=IF(MONTH(A1)>6,MONTH(A1)-6,MONTH(A1)+6)**

This is the fiscal month number in which July is the first month